# Resized browser is adding 1px or taking 1px of height from css somewhere, why?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have one large grid and 4 smaller, 1 is on the left with large image, and other 4 are on the right with smaller images.
Something like this:

```
<div class="large-grid">large grid code/codes</div>
<div class="small-grids">small grids code/codes</div>
```

I am using 1920 x 1080 screen.
On my screen size, both sides, both divs are 294px high.

Ctrl + minus twice, on 80% resized browser and left is 293px, right is 292px.

Can't put all code here so here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/4VSFq/

Comment: Often times, when you zoom in or out, the browser wont calculate things perfectly. It's the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's something wrong with your line height or something like that. When there is 2 line of paragraph it get's 1 px on it so do something for that :D